# How can we print line numbers to the log in java

Tags: java, logging

How to print line numbers to the log. Say when outputting some information to the log, I also want to print the line number where that output is in the source code. As we can see in the stack trace, it displays the line number where the exception has occurred. Stack trace is available on the exception object.

Other alternative could be like manually including the line number when printing to the log. Is there any other way?

Comment: see @Juan's underappreciated answer below for a short and sweet one-liner! i just gave up 15 points rep downvoting all other answers :v and upvoting Juan's

Answer (score 115):

From [Angsuman Chakraborty](https://web.archive.org/web/20100818065334/http://blog.taragana.com:80/index.php/archive/core-java-how-to-get-java-source-code-line-number-file-name-in-code/) (archived) :

```
/** Get the current line number.
 * @return int - Current line number.
 */
public static int getLineNumber() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();
}
```

Comment: This will always return the line number of the return statement in the called method and not necessarily the line number of the method call.

Comment: Does not the [2] get the frame above getLineNumber()? ([1] being getLineNumber(), and [0] being getStackTrace(), presumably)

Comment: I played around a bit and if you use blah.getStackTrace[3].getLineNumber() as the method body it returns the line number of where the method was called.

Comment: The index will change based on the JVM version. I believe it changed from 1.4 to 1.5.

Comment: This is excellent. You have to do some experimentation depending on how deep the call is made, but that's okay. We're all explorers right? One thing I did while debugging was iterate over the first ten entries and printed the entire stacktrace to the log - this helped me easily nail down which one I wanted, then of course I removed it because that's just extra log clutter I don't need.

Comment: For JDK 1.6 : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber();  Will Work Perfectly

Comment: Hey @SimonBuchan, The guy has a name :)
I wrote that article long back.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger this line for each instruction executed? I guess some kind of visitor. @SimonBuchan

Comment: Use new Throwable().getStackTrace() to get a consistent index for your calling function, regardless of JVM. (Instead of Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())

Comment: This looks innocent enough, but I wonder what the cost of `getStackTrace()` is. It seems heavy handed. I was hoping there was a compiler solution / macro, that would hard code the numbers at compile time, like c++ does.
Still - this is the best of the available answers.

Answer (score 80):

We ended up using a custom class like this for our Android work:

```
import android.util.Log;    
public class DebugLog {
 public final static boolean DEBUG = true;    
 public static void log(String message) {
  if (DEBUG) {
    String fullClassName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();
    String className = fullClassName.substring(fullClassName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
    int lineNumber = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();

    Log.d(className + "." + methodName + "():" + lineNumber, message);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your solution, it is working fine for me to display the line numbers for log info.... thanks again.  I am looking forward for your great solutions in android.

Comment: I'd do some more research into this code before using it - when I posted the code, getStackTrace()[3] worked. It might be dependent on the version of Android or JVM, or some other factor.

Comment: this answer doesn't work it shows line no and class name and function name of DebugLog class not line no of caller from other class

Comment: @Rahul it should be `getStackTrace()[3]` instead of `getStackTrace()[2]`

Comment: @user5480949: Use "new Throwable().getStackTrace()" to get a consistent index for your calling function, regardless of JVM. (Instead of Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())

Answer (score 41):

Quick and dirty way:

```
System.out.println("I'm in line #" + 
    new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
```

With some more details:

```
StackTraceElement l = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0];
System.out.println(
    l.getClassName()+"/"+l.getMethodName()+":"+l.getLineNumber());
```

That will output something like this:

```
com.example.mytest.MyClass/myMethod:103
```

Comment: `System.out.println("i am here: " + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0]);` gives me all the details I need :)

Comment: Note that the JVM is not guaranteed to give a stacktrace where this is correct.  I do not believe Hotspot makes that guarantee either (but its stacktraces are normally correct).

Comment: very clean, class StackTraceElement l = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1]; work with me

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Use "new Throwable().getStackTrace()" to get a consistent index for your calling function, regardless of JVM. (Instead of Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())

Comment: @LucBloom in the Old days you were not guaranteed that a stack trace was accurate.

Comment: Or as a one-liner in kotlin: `with(Exception().stackTrace[0]) { println("$className/$methodName:$lineNumber") }`

Answer (score 25):

I am compelled to answer by not answering your question.  I'm assuming that you are looking for the line number solely to support debugging.  There are better ways.  There are hackish ways to get the current line.  All I've seen are slow.  You are better off using a logging framework like that in java.util.logging package or [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html).  Using these packages you can configure your logging information to include context down to the class name.  Then each log message would be unique enough to know where it came from.  As a result, your code will have a 'logger' variable that you call via

> `logger.debug("a really descriptive message")`

instead of

> `System.out.println("a really descriptive message")`

Answer (score 16):

Log4J allows you to include the line number as part of its output pattern.  See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html for details on how to do this (the key element in the conversion pattern is "L").  However, the Javadoc does include the following:

> WARNING Generating caller location
>   information is extremely slow. It's
>   use should be avoided unless execution
>   speed is not an issue.

Comment: The underlying mechanism have become much faster in more recent versions of the JVM, but it should still be used sparingly.

Answer (score 7):

The code posted by @simon.buchan will work...

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber()
```

But if you call it in a method it will always return the line number of the line in the method so rather use the code snippet inline.

Comment: I guessed the '2' was to get the line number of getLineNumber() caller.

Comment: @simon.buchan - edit your answer (as per my last comment). I don't want to steal your rep for your answer.

Comment: Or change the 2 to another number. Depending how deep it is nested.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend using a logging toolkit such as [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/). Logging is configurable via properties files at runtime, and you can turn on / off features such as line number / filename logging.

Looking at the javadoc for the [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) gives you the full list of options - what you're after is %L.

Answer (score 7):

I use this  little method that outputs the trace and line number of the method that called it.

```
 Log.d(TAG, "Where did i put this debug code again?   " + Utils.lineOut());
```

Double click the output to go to that source code line!

You might need to adjust the level value depending on where you put your code.

```
public static String lineOut() {
    int level = 3;
    StackTraceElement[] traces;
    traces = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    return (" at "  + traces[level] + " " );
}
```

Comment: Where does this `Util` come from ?

Comment: @benj Utils is just general class that you have control over. You could put the method in any class (note the method is static).

Comment: OK, I just wanted to be sure. Thanks for this nice bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't guarantee line number consistency with code, especially if it is compiled for release. I would not recommend using line numbers for that purpose anyway, it would be better to give a payload of the place where the exception was raised (the trivial method being to set the message to include the details of the method call).

You might like to look at exception enrichment as a technique to improve exception handling 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-enrichment.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's been compiled for release this isn't possible. You might want to look into something like Log4J which will automatically give you enough information to determine pretty closely where the logged code occurred.

Answer (score 0):

first the general method (in an utility class, in plain old java1.4 code though, you may have to rewrite it for java1.5 and more)

```
/**
 * Returns the first "[class#method(line)]: " of the first class not equal to "StackTraceUtils" and aclass. <br />
 * Allows to get past a certain class.
 * @param aclass class to get pass in the stack trace. If null, only try to get past StackTraceUtils. 
 * @return "[class#method(line)]: " (never empty, because if aclass is not found, returns first class past StackTraceUtils)
 */
public static String getClassMethodLine(final Class aclass)  {
    final StackTraceElement st = getCallingStackTraceElement(aclass);
    final String amsg = "[" + st.getClassName() + "#" + st.getMethodName() + "(" + st.getLineNumber()
    +")] <" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ">: ";
    return amsg;
}
```

Then the specific utility method to get the right stackElement:

```
/**
   * Returns the first stack trace element of the first class not equal to "StackTraceUtils" or "LogUtils" and aClass. <br />
   * Stored in array of the callstack. <br />
   * Allows to get past a certain class.
   * @param aclass class to get pass in the stack trace. If null, only try to get past StackTraceUtils. 
   * @return stackTraceElement (never null, because if aClass is not found, returns first class past StackTraceUtils)
   * @throws AssertionFailedException if resulting statckTrace is null (RuntimeException)
   */
  public static StackTraceElement getCallingStackTraceElement(final Class aclass) {
    final Throwable           t         = new Throwable();
    final StackTraceElement[] ste       = t.getStackTrace();
    int index = 1;
    final int limit = ste.length;
    StackTraceElement   st        = ste[index];
    String              className = st.getClassName();
    boolean aclassfound = false;
    if(aclass == null) {
        aclassfound = true;
    }
    StackTraceElement   resst = null;
    while(index < limit) {
        if(shouldExamine(className, aclass) == true) {
            if(resst == null) {
                resst = st;
            }
            if(aclassfound == true) {
                final StackTraceElement ast = onClassfound(aclass, className, st);
                if(ast != null) {
                    resst = ast;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(aclass != null && aclass.getName().equals(className) == true) {
                    aclassfound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        index = index + 1;
        st        = ste[index];
        className = st.getClassName();
    }
    if(isNull(resst))  {
        throw new AssertionFailedException(StackTraceUtils.getClassMethodLine() + " null argument:" + "stack trace should null"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    return resst;
  }

  static private boolean shouldExamine(String className, Class aclass) {
      final boolean res = StackTraceUtils.class.getName().equals(className) == false && (className.endsWith(LOG_UTILS
        ) == false || (aclass !=null && aclass.getName().endsWith(LOG_UTILS)));
      return res;
  }

  static private StackTraceElement onClassfound(Class aclass, String className, StackTraceElement st) {
      StackTraceElement   resst = null;
      if(aclass != null && aclass.getName().equals(className) == false)
      {
          resst = st;
      }
      if(aclass == null)
      {
          resst = st;
      }
      return resst;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logger that we use.

it wraps around Android Logger and display class name, method name and line number.

http://www.hautelooktech.com/2011/08/15/android-logging/

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599298/779408). In that method you can jump to your line code, when you double click on LogCat's row.

Also you can use this code to get line number:

```
public static int getLineNumber()
{
    int lineNumber = 0;
    StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement = Thread.currentThread()
            .getStackTrace();
    int currentIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < stackTraceElement.length; i++) {
        if (stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName().compareTo("getLineNumber") == 0)
        {
            currentIndex = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    lineNumber = stackTraceElement[currentIndex].getLineNumber();

    return lineNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX;

static {
    // Finds out the index of "this code" in the returned stack Trace - funny but it differs in JDK 1.5 and 1.6
    int i = 0;
    for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
        i++;
        if (ste.getClassName().equals(Trace.class.getName())) {
            break;
        }
    }
    CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX = i;
}

private String methodName() {
    StackTraceElement ste=Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX+1];
    return ste.getMethodName()+":"+ste.getLineNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These all get you the line numbers of your current thread and method which work great if you use a try catch where you are expecting an exception. But if you want to catch any unhandled exception then you are using the default uncaught exception handler and current thread will return the line number of the handler function, not the class method that threw the exception. Instead of using Thread.currentThread() simply use the Throwable passed in by the exception handler:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {              
                if(fShowUncaughtMessage(e,t))               
                    System.exit(1);
            }
        });
```

In the above use e.getStackTrace()[0] in your handler function (fShowUncaughtMessage) to get the offender.

Answer (score 0):

**Below code is tested code for logging line no class name and method name from where logging method is called**

```
public class Utils {
/*
 * debug variable enables/disables all log messages to logcat
 * Useful to disable prior to app store submission
 */
public static final boolean debug = true;

/*
 * l method used to log passed string and returns the
 * calling file as the tag, method and line number prior
 * to the string's message
 */
public static void l(String s) {
    if (debug) {
        String[] msg = trace(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(), 3);
        Log.i(msg[0], msg[1] + s);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

/*
 * l (tag, string)
 * used to pass logging messages as normal but can be disabled
 * when debug == false
 */
public static void l(String t, String s) {
    if (debug) {
        Log.i(t, s);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

/*
 * trace
 * Gathers the calling file, method, and line from the stack
 * returns a string array with element 0 as file name and 
 * element 1 as method[line]
 */
public static String[] trace(final StackTraceElement e[], final int level) {
    if (e != null && e.length >= level) {
        final StackTraceElement s = e[level];
        if (s != null) { return new String[] {
                e[level].getFileName(), e[level].getMethodName() + "[" + e[level].getLineNumber() + "]"
        };}
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `stackLevel` depends on depth you call this method. You can try from 0 to a large number to see what difference.

If `stackLevel` is legal, you will get string like `java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1536)`

```
public static String getCodeLocationInfo(int stackLevel) {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        if (stackLevel < 0 || stackLevel >= stackTraceElements.length) {
            return "Stack Level Out Of StackTrace Bounds";
        }
        StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = stackTraceElements[stackLevel];
        String fullClassName = stackTraceElement.getClassName();
        String methodName = stackTraceElement.getMethodName();
        String fileName = stackTraceElement.getFileName();
        int lineNumber = stackTraceElement.getLineNumber();

        return String.format("%s.%s(%s:%s)", fullClassName, methodName, fileName, lineNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the feature I implemented in this lib 
[XDDLib](https://github.com/adherencegoo/XDDLib). (But, it's for android)

```
Lg.d("int array:", intArrayOf(1, 2, 3), "int list:", listOf(4, 5, 6))
```

[image]

One click on the **underlined text** to navigate to where the log command is

That `StackTraceElement` is determined by the first element outside this library. Thus, anywhere outside this lib will be legal, including `lambda expression`, `static initialization block`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the index in the `getStackTrace()[3]` method signals the amount of threads the triggering line travels until the actual .getStackTrace() method excluding the executing line.

This means that if the `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[X].getLineNumber();` line is executed from 3 nested methods *above*, the index number must be **3**.

Example:

First layer

```
private static String message(String TAG, String msg) {

    int lineNumber = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3].getLineNumber();

    return ".(" + TAG + ".java:"+ lineNumber +")" + " " + msg;
}
```

Second Layer

```
private static void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Third Layer

```
public static void normal(
        String TAG,
        String message
) {
    print(
            message(
                    TAG,
                    message
            )
    );
}
```

Executing Line:

```
    Print.normal(TAG, "StatelessDispatcher");
```

As someone that has not received any formal education on IT, this has been mind opening on how compilers work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which prints the line number.

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber()
```

Create a global public static method to make printing Logs easier.

```
  public static void Loge(Context context, String strMessage, int strLineNumber) {
    
        Log.e(context.getClass().getSimpleName(), strLineNumber + " : " + strMessage);
  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My way it works for me

```
String str = "select os.name from os where os.idos="+nameid;  try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(str);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            a = rs.getString("os.n1ame");//<<<----Here is the ERROR          
        }
        stmt.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("error line : " + e.getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber());            
        return a;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use -> Reporter.log("");