# How to insert a log in LogCat that when I click on it jumps to its line in code?

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I want to insert a log in LogCat that when I click on it jumps to its line like some error logs that are generated by system.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found it:

```
public static void showLogCat(String tag, String msg) {

        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement = Thread.currentThread()
                .getStackTrace();
        int currentIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < stackTraceElement.length; i++) {
            if (stackTraceElement[i].getMethodName().compareTo("showLogCat") == 0)
            {
                currentIndex = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        String fullClassName = stackTraceElement[currentIndex].getClassName();
        String className = fullClassName.substring(fullClassName
                .lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String methodName = stackTraceElement[currentIndex].getMethodName();
        String lineNumber = String
                .valueOf(stackTraceElement[currentIndex].getLineNumber());

        Log.i(tag, msg);
        Log.i(tag + " position", "at " + fullClassName + "." + methodName + "("
                + className + ".java:" + lineNumber + ")");

    }
```

Its usage:

```
showLogCat("tag", "message");
```

Comment: If I call your method from other than activity or fragment, it gives a an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on stackTraceElement[currentIndex].getClassName();

Answer (score 4):

**The important thing is to insert `"(X:Y)"` in your log message, while `X` is your desired *file name* and `Y` is your desired *line number* in `X`.** *(I learned it from [@breceivemail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599298/5318303))*. So try:

```java
public static void log(final String tag, final String msg) {
    final StackTraceElement stackTrace = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1];

    String fileName = stackTrace.getFileName();
    if (fileName == null) fileName="";  // It is necessary if you want to use proguard obfuscation.

    final String info = stackTrace.getMethodName() + " (" + fileName + ":"
            + stackTrace.getLineNumber() + ")";

    Log.LEVEL(tag, info + ": " + msg);
}
```

**Note**: The `LEVEL` is the log level and can be `v`, `d`, `i`, `w`, `e` or `wtf`.

Now you can use `log(tag, msg)` instead of `Log.LEVEL(tag, msg)`.

---

Example:

**MainActivity.java**:

```java
...
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        log("Test Tag", "Hello World!");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
    ...
```

The output:

```java
12-30 14:24:45.343 ? I/Test Tag: onCreate (MainActivity.java:10): Hello World!
```

And `MainActivity.java:10` automatically would be a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597623/how-to-insert-a-log-in-logcat-that-when-i-click-on-it-jumps-to-its-line-in-code#answer-41395273) and you can click on it!

---

You can also assign following value to `info` variable if you want more verbose log:

```java
final String info = stackTrace.getClassName() + "." + stackTrace.getMethodName() + " ("
            + fileName + ":" + stackTrace.getLineNumber() + ")\n";
```

So the output of above example would be:

```java
12-30 14:33:07.360 ? I/Test Tag: com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:11)
                                 Hello World!
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use this Tree with Timber.

```
class MyLinkingTimberTree : Timber.DebugTree() {
    override fun createStackElementTag(element: StackTraceElement): String? {
        return makeClickableLineNumber(element)
    }

    private fun makeClickableLineNumber(
        element: StackTraceElement
    ): String {
        val className = element.fileName
        val methodName = element.methodName
        val lineNumber = element.lineNumber
        val fileName = element.fileName
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder(className)
        .append(".")
        .append(methodName)
        .append(" (")
        .append(fileName)
        .append(":")
        .append(lineNumber)
        .append(")  ")
        return stringBuilder.toString()
    }
}
```

And then just instantiate it like this:

```
class MyApplication: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(MyLinkingTimberTree())
        }
    }
}
```

Then just use Timber normally:

```
Timber.d("Currently Signed in:")
```

And this is the result. Nice, isn't it? I hope you enjoy using it as much as I enjoyed making it! ;)

[image: Logcat with a link!]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it .. Follow the example as answered on [SO - logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4332163/786337)

Answer (score 0):

## To answer the question in a simple way:

respecter cette règle :

```
{FileName}.{ext}:{LigneNumber}

e.g. MainActivity.java:10
```

which gives a sample as below

```
Log.d(TAG, "onResume: MainActivity.java:10");
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer to the question, but perhaps it's a "close enough" workaround.

1. Highlight the log text
2. Press CTRL-SHIFT-F
3. Double-Click on the search result.

If the text is highlighted before you press CTRL-SHIFT-F, then you don't need to type or copy/paste it in.
[image: screenshot of Search Results]

If your searches tend to produce too many results, you can use live templates to make unique logcat entries:

Create a live template to insert the Class, Method, and Line-Number (at the time of writing).  I use "logi."   Yes, the line number will become less and less accurate as you continue to write, but it can still function as a way to make your log entries more "findable."

[image: Screenshot of Live Template]