# Android Log - print link to line of code in c++ file

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-logcat

If you print in log [`(fileName:lineNumber)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10597623/1771055) you get a nice link in Android Monitor that gets you to that code line when you click on it. This however does not seem to work for my cpp files. Is there a way to achieve this for c++ files?

---

**Edit**

I already know how to create string `(fileName:lineNumber)`, but when it is printed in Android Monitor it is not a clickable link. The question is how to make clickable.

Comment: [This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/line) might be helpful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I already print `(fileName:lineNumber)`. The question is how to make it a link in Android monitor.

Answer (score 2):

To appear as a clickable link in the Android studio *Logcat* window, `(filename.cpp:filenumber)` should be associated at least with one file that is part of your AS project:

[image: C++ logcat extract]

You can see that some system logs are resolved to clickable links, while the others are not.

[image: Java logcat extract]

In the example above, `Socket.java` is part of public API, while `PlaneSocketImpl.java` is not, therefore AS does not show a link for the latter.

Comment: Well my cpp files are a part of my project, but through CMakeLists.txt. Perhaps c++ link are just not supported.

Comment: How did you add c++ files to you project?

Comment: Just regular C++ support enabled. Maybe the trick is that I am on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 5.

Comment: So there is still hope for me :)