# Getting error number of an exception object

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I have a program developed and it has a single entry point. A Try catch block is surrounding it.

```
try {
            Runner runner = new Runner();
            // Adhoc code
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
            runner.setupVariables();
            runner.setLookAndFeel();
            runner.startSessionFactory();
            runner.setupApplicationVariables();
            runner.setupDirectories();
            // This will be used to test out frames in development mode
            if (Runner.isProduction == true) {
                execute();
            } else {
                test();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                SwingHelper.showErrorMessageMainFrame(e.getMessage());
            Logger.getRootLogger().error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But suppose a null pointer exception is thrown, the message box is empty since the Exception doesn't contain a message. For this I added a logic-

```
 if(e instanceof NullPointerException){
        NullPointerException n =(NullPointerException) e;
        SwingHelper.showErrorMessageMainFrame("Unexpected Exception due at ");
    }else{
SwingHelper.showErrorMessageMainFrame(e.getMessage());
}
```

This works all fine but I also want the line number to be displayed. How can I get it done. How can I get the line number of the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115008/how-can-we-print-line-numbers-to-the-log-in-java), you can use this snippet:

```
public static int getLineNumber() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();
}
```

Althought is recommended to use a logging library such as [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html).

Comment: Why `[2]`? Thanks agent 007!

Answer (score 1):

The metadata for the exception is stored in [StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) class, which you can get from your exception by calling [getStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace%28%29).

Example of using it is:

```
if (e instanceof NullPointerException) {
    NullPointerException n = (NullPointerException) e;
    StackTraceElement stackTrace = n.getStackTrace()[0];
    SwingHelper.showErrorMessageMainFrame("Unexpected Exception due at " + stactTrace.getLineNumber());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(e instanceof NullPointerException){
    NullPointerException n =(NullPointerException) e;
    SwingHelper.showErrorMessageMainFrame("Unexpected Exception due at line" + e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
} else {
    SwingHelper.showErrorMessageMainFrame(e.getMessage());
}
```

Wow I was ninja'd by those above...

EDIT: Forgot to indent