# Dynamically get the current line number

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way in Java to dynamically get the current line number through reflection or some awesome API? Just like when exceptions occur, the line number gets printed out in the stack trace like this:

```
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
```

Now is there a way to print or log like in the below code?

```
log.error("Error in: " + this.getClass.getName() + "at line #"+ this.getClass.getActualLine());
```

You may ask, why don't I simply print the line number? Well because the code may get deleted or added before the specific log.error() method call.

Comment: Doesn't PatternLayout of logging API's comes handy for this?

Comment: You could create a `new Throwable` and access the stack trace elements. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115008/how-can-we-print-line-numbers-to-the-log-in-java

Comment: @Andreas: you don't need a `Throwable`: [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) is sufficient.

Comment: @Joachim hmmm, this returns `-1` for the line number for me ...

Comment: @Andreas: maybe your class was compiled without debug information? According to the JavaDoc that happens when "that information is unavailable".

Comment: @Joachim The Throwable appraoch works at the same place, just `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` does not ...

Comment: Ah got it - the elements of the arrays are different ....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to use the Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() method to create a set of functions that work together to produce the line number of the code that called the first method, like so:

```
/** @return The line number of the code that ran this method
 * @author Brian_Entei */
public static int getLineNumber() {
    return ___8drrd3148796d_Xaf();
}

/** This methods name is ridiculous on purpose to prevent any other method
 * names in the stack trace from potentially matching this one.
 * 
 * @return The line number of the code that called the method that called
 *         this method(Should only be called by getLineNumber()).
 * @author Brian_Entei */
private static int ___8drrd3148796d_Xaf() {
    boolean thisOne = false;
    int thisOneCountDown = 1;
    StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for(StackTraceElement element : elements) {
        String methodName = element.getMethodName();
        int lineNum = element.getLineNumber();
        if(thisOne && (thisOneCountDown == 0)) {
            return lineNum;
        } else if(thisOne) {
            thisOneCountDown--;
        }
        if(methodName.equals("___8drrd3148796d_Xaf")) {
            thisOne = true;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Hope this helps! I put these in a utility class so that they are out of the way, but still easily accessible. The second method is private to prevent any other method other than the first method from calling it so that it always works correctly.

Comment: Looks like it is now, woah. I'm glad it works for you guys.

Comment: That works great. Also in stack trace there could be numerous calls from system files. So I find my class by making                 if ((element.className.contains("my package name")) && (!element.className.contains("Class that contains my log function"))
                )

Answer (score 55):

You can create a [`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) and use its [`StackTraceElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html):

```
  System.err.println(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
```

As @Joachim said, you can also use [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29), e.g. like

```
  System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber());
```

Be aware that the second approach returns a somewhat different array - you need to use the array element with index 1 to get the **current** line number, since it includes the call to `getStackTrace()` itself as the first element.

Also note the comments about Logging and performance from @Joachim's answer.

Comment: May yield different results on some JVMs. At least on IBM JVM for AIX the stack included the throwable constructors. See getStackTrace's javadoc: `The zeroth element of the array (assuming the array's length is non-zero) represents the top of the stack, which is the last method invocation in the sequence. Typically, this is the point at which this throwable was created and thrown.` - typically, not guaranteed. So Brian_Entei's solution is more resilient.

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber() helped me

Answer (score 17):

First of all: If *anything*, then the logging pattern (or layouter, or whatever your logging framework calls that part) should do this. The logger call in your code should *only* write the actual business information. Information about the where should be added by the logger.

Next: getting that kind of operation is expensive (in terms of time), because Java is not optimized for this. At runtime, the JVM need to inspect its state, load/parse debug information and find the line number corresponding to a given instruction. That's why this kind of information is usually just given when an exception occurs (in which case we already have a problem and *know* that the time spent will usually be worth it).

And last but not least: **if** for some reason you need that information on your own, you can use [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29) and inspect the second [`StackTraceElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) on it.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from JDK9 you can use the StackWalker.
This gave me around a 50% of speed increase over using `getStackTrace()`.

```
int get_line_number() {
    return StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.SHOW_HIDDEN_FRAMES).walk(
      (s) -> s.skip(1).findFirst()).get().getLineNumber();
}
```

My stream could be done better but I have no experience with it, and I really don't like streams in general, so feel free to edit my post to improve this part.

Comment: FYI, this is not correct syntax for  groovy

Answer (score 3):

One can also get the *Exception line number* using following snippet. Use following util method in your util class.

```
 public static int getExceptionLineNumber(Exception e, String methodNameExp) 
 {
    StackTraceElement ele = Arrays.stream(e.getStackTrace()).filter(o -> o.getMethodName().equals(methodNameExp)).findAny().orElse(null);
    if(ele != null){
        return ele.getLineNumber();
    }
    return -1;
 }
```

From catch block you can call like below :

```
catch (Exception e){
        logger.info("Exception line number "+ Util.getExceptionLineNumber(e, new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName()));
    }
```

Hope this works! :)