# Effectively get line numbers in java source code at compile time

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a exception class where in which i want to pass the current line number

```
     line 70:
     line 71: throw new 
              LightException(FailureType.NOT_FOUND,this.getClass().getName(),linenum);
```

**Is there a way to get linenum as 72 here without hardcoding it?**
Does eclipse offer anything that would get replaced into hardcoded line numbers at compile time.So that i don't have to put ugly hard-code line numbers

```
class LightException(FailureType type,String className,int lineNum)  extends RuntimeException 
{

LightException(FailureType type,String className,int lineNum){..
//
}

@Override
@Override public Throwable fillInStackTrace() { 
return this;
 }
}
```

I do not need to log the entire stack trace and unnecessarily filling the stack trace for all exceptions.I want to add the line number from  where the exception was thrown.
**Any code which can be resolved at compile time into constants?**

If not then I can write a simple utitly to pre-process my code which can read lines and replace a special constant _my_line_num by the line number but something should exist.

I feel some build tool like gradle can do this.

Comment: AFAIK I don't think Eclipse offers anything like this.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473148/dynamically-get-the-current-line-number)

Comment: I didn't want that.If i have to fill the stack trace and get the line number of it.There is no point in avoiding it.I would rather have a simple utility do it for me

Comment: Why don't you want to use the stack trace? Is it just a performance question? If so make sure it's a real issue before you make something complicated

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is [good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473148/dynamically-get-the-current-line-number) or not but you can place this:

```
int linenumber = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();
```

as a parameter in your exception's contractor and display it as you need.

Comment: Haven't you read the OP's request *I do not need to log the entire stack trace and unnecessarily filling the stack trace for all exceptions.*

Comment: @Madhan you can give it a try

Comment: This is very slow.