# Is there an Android equivalent to iOS´s (swifts) fatalError()?

Tags: android, swift, fatal-error

If something happens in my app I want to kill the app there and then. In swift I can use fatalError(), is there a java equivalent?

Comment: Put this line of code in your main activity when you want to kill your app- android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: why swift? bad tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't there's any method equivalent to `fatalError` in Android.

If you want to kill the entire process then you can use `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`.

To mimic the same behaviour of `fatalError` you'll probably have to implement it yourself.

The behaviour you'll need to add besides killing the process is

- to log a message, you can to this by using `Log`
- print the file and line number, for this you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473148/dynamically-get-the-current-line-number) thread on SO

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin's `Preconditions.kt` file includes an `error(message: Any)` function that, in turn, throws an `IllegalStateException`[1].

As long as you're not swallowing the exception, it should kill the app much like `fatalError()`.

[1] [Source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/423aeb9a08582f88a974afdebdb7d17924ec8980/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Preconditions.kt#L143)