# How to make Java compiler generate line numbers in compiled code

Tags: java, javac

I have a hello world program called *A.class*. It was compiled using command `javac A.java`. All it does is print *"hello world"*.

Next, I compiled using `javac -g A.java`. I am expecting to see line numbers, but can't see. Any idea what happened?

I do see very minor differences in some kind of special characters between .class file of javac compiled, and javac -g compiled. But I can't see any line numbers.

My curiosity for this is because I want to find what kind of impact line numbers may have on performance. Second, I want to know how log4j etc maintain line numbers for logging. Thanks.

Comment: -g is for generating debug information.  class files are bytecode, not human readable.  You can use javap to disassemble a class file.

Comment: Have you actually pasted the contents of the `.class` file into the question?  Have you really done that?  And if I may ask, why have you done it twice?

Comment: First one is with javac. Second one is compiled with javac -g <<<. Notice the "g". No line number! Javap is great, but still no line number!

Comment: Uh.  Wow.  What are you trying to achieve?  Forget about your solution and tell us why you would want this.

Comment: I want this to see if there is any kind of performance impact in maintaining line numbers, and secondly, I want to see how log4j (and other loggers) manage to obtain line number for logging. So I need this real bad. But I am not able to see line numbers in javac -g generated bytecode. Help!

Comment: @ApurvaSingh It's better if you enter the source code instead of the bytecode. Because there is no point entering the bytecode. If you enter the source code you may get the answer more quicker.

Comment: If you need to know how certain lines perform, there are plenty of ways to profile your code. The most brain-dead simple of these is to literally print or log execution times before and after a given line or method.

Comment: Not gonna work Jim.. print and log have their own time burn. It will distort my timing. I just wanna know where are the line numbers! Does javac -g generate line numbers? If yes, then where are they. How does log4j figure out line numbers.

Comment: Well, I am not a pro of java bytecode, but I'm pretty sure that you will never see any line number in the bytecode or in any compiled code of any language! This thread seems to have some hints to your second question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115008/how-can-we-print-line-numbers-to-the-log-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compile command is good, `-g` turns on generation of debug information, indeed. BTW: line numbers are generated by default, need `-g:none` or similar to turn this off.

What's missing is a way to meaningfully inspect the generated `.class` file, similar to how a tool would use it. Try:

```
$ javap -l -c A.class
```

`-l` turns on printing of line number tables.
`-c` turns on printing of disassembled bytecode instructions (might be interesting since line number tables relate source line numbers to bytecode instructions).