# cannot debug in eclipse after bytecode enhancement

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, line-numbers, byte-code-enhancement

We have a very old java project that consisted of some sub projects, in one of them it used a bytecode enhancer jdodoclet, the whole thing is built by ant script.

Now whenever try to do debug of the project, once we go into classes of that particular project, we cannot only do a step into, but not step over, rendering debug pretty pointless.

so when debug first starts, eclipse will give us a warning
[image: warning java breakpoint]

But it continues as normal.

and once we step into any classes of the program, eclipse cannot show us where we are in the source code nor the line number (ok, line number is the reason)

[image: no line number]

I did checked and double checked the compiler settings

[image]

and restarted eclipse.

but still it doesn't work.

Does anyone has any suggestion towards this problem?

Comment: Looks like the bytecode “enhancer” removed the debug information in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to recompile that code with debug information (line numbers) included, check this answer [How to make Java compiler generate line numbers in compiled code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376559/how-to-make-java-compiler-generate-line-numbers-in-compiled-code).
The Eclipse setting is for that exactly purpose: when You compile Your code in Eclipse it will add debug info to generated .class files but it will not let You debug code compiled without this settings.