# Is there way to specify current line number in log4j pattern

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a pattern to output to console and log file in following format:

```
[INFO]  17:31:12 - Checking Bla Bla Bla 
[INFO]  17:31:12 - ************* Starting *********************
[INFO]  17:31:12 - Testing Begins
```

is there any way to append line count so that it looks like:

```
[001][INFO] 17:31:12 - Checking Bla Bla Bla 
[002][INFO] 17:31:12 - ************* Starting *********************
[003][INFO] 17:31:12 - Testing Begins
```

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115008/how-can-we-print-line-numbers-to-the-log-in-java

Comment: I doubt that the standard appenders would do this, but you can always write your own appender.

Comment: You want to append the count of lines in the log file?  Like literally how many lines the log file is up to that point?  I'm sure there's a standard unix command that could do it, and at least one Java class that will track lines as they are read.

Answer (score 8):

In Log4j 1, the symbols can be seen here
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Line Number is %L.

In Log4j 2, the symbol is also %L

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html#Pattern_Layout

Answer (score 5):

Try below conversion pattern

```
ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Is it line number or count of log lines ordered in sequence ?

if it is line number you can use %L (Used to output the line number 
from where the logging request was issued.)
```

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html