# Print current line number in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to print the current line number(line number of ide) of a certain code from intellij. How do I do that?

```
1 System.out.print(getCurrentLineNo());//sample code
2 System.out.print(getCurrentLineNo());//sample code
3 System.out.print(getCurrentLineNo());//sample code
4 System.out.print(getCurrentLineNo());//sample code
```

Comment: use debugging mode https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/starting-the-debugger-session.html

Comment: hmm I am trying to print it in my way. like this code.
print("I am in line number " + getCurrentLineNo());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the stack trace element and call `getLineNumber`.

```
public static int getCurrentLineNumber() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();
}
```

Note that I used an index of `2` because that refers to the frame of the method that calls `getCurrentLineNumber`. If you are just doing this inline, i.e. like this:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber());
```

You should use an index of `1` instead.

Note that an index of `0` refers to the frame of the `getStackTrace` method.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it too expensive to get StatckTrace for that, but it can help you for some debug.

```
System.out.println(new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());
```

Also, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115008/9719337)

Answer (score 1):

You can get line number like this...

```
public static int getCurrentLineNo() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();
    }
```